# How to get the outcome of a composite github action?

Tags: github-actions

I have a composite action with multiple steps. The last step must be executed, if the first step fails (and must not be skipped du the failure of any prior step). For non composite actions, I could simply do the following. However, within my composite action `steps.first.outcome` is empty. What am I missing?

```
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: 'First step'
      id: first
      run: some-command
      shell: bash

    # [some more steps]

    - name: 'Last step'
      if: ${{ always() && steps.first.outcome != `success`}}
      run: another-command
      shell: bash
```

Comment: It looks just fine, are you sure that you posted the full example? There was an issue looong time ago, which is already fixed: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1578

Comment: Also, these days if you click on "Rerun", you have the option to enable debug mode. If the above doesn't solve it, please show the logs.

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem might be that I am still on GHES 3.4.3? So december 2021 is not too long ago, I guess? Also, I don't see an option to rerun in debug?